# How to declare anonymous mixin using a type parameter in Scala

Tags: scala

There have been some questions asked that are somewhat related to this problem, but they don't seem to fit quite right.

I'm using the Cake pattern to slide a "Storage" system in place in production code, and a stub storage system in for testing purposes.  This is all great, but there's a class that's being instantiated within the original class that also needs to have this stub storage system mixed in.  Since it's hidden inside the implementation, I don't have access to it.

Things look like this:

```
class Main { this: Storage =>
  ...
  val used = Used(...)
  ...
}

class Used { this: Storage =>
  ...
}
```

When testing "Used" I simply `new Used with StubStorage` and off I go.  I used to do the same with `Main` but that was before it made use of `Used`.  Now that `Main` makes a naive instantiation of `Used` I've got this problem.

I wanted to try it this way:

```
class Main[T <: Storage] { this: T =>
  ...
  val used = Used[T](...)
  ...
}

class Used[T <: Storage] { this: T =>
  ...
}
object Used {
  def apply[T <: Storage](...) = new Used(...) with T
}
```

But of course that doesn't work because the compiler doesn't have enough information to discover `T`.  Is there a magic recipe for this?  I've played around with it for a bit and it seems to be cumbersome enough that the standard OO injection method is actually less trouble, but I could be missing something.

I've looked at the implicit Factory concept but I can't pound that into shape to work for mixins.

**EDIT**: It's amazing the clarity that writing the question publicly gives. :)  I haven't solved the problem the way I originally intended, but there is a simple solution to the actual problem:

```
trait UsedProvider {
  def createUsed = Used.apply _
}

class Main { this: Storage with UsedProvider =>
  val used = createUsed(...)
}
```

Then I would just do the following in the test: `new Main with StubStorage with StubUsedProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't solved your original problem either but have you considered using an abstract class for `Main` and provide the value for `used` where you need it?

```
abstract class Main { this: Storage =>
  val s = "s"
  val used: Used
}
```

Then instantiate like this:

```
val main = new Main with StubStorage { val used = new Used(s) with StubStorage }
```

Comment: That would only allow me to create one and I need more than one, which isn't something that was clear in the original question.  What I need is a factory method that allows me to create them when I need them.  So I'm just using the good ol' cake pattern again to give me that dependency.